# Custom solar 5v iPhone charger

Tags: iphone, customization, charger

I have a solar panel that emits 5 volts, and I would like to try to charge my iPhone with it. Should I connect the I/O wires directly behind the lightning plug, or is the big transformer block important?

I guess the block is used to change the voltage to 5 volts so that the iPhone can handle it, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: I would make a frankenstein wire, but I don't know how to make one with a lightning cable.

Comment: what is a frankenstein cable?

Comment: @DanielEnzlin [A highly customized cable:](http://i.imgur.com/7kFUWWc.jpg)

Comment: @klanomath That picture is so good... Hey, why won't it turn on? You mean it can't generate electricity?

Comment: A Frankenstein wire is when you take a cord, cut it, strip it in part, and then connect the red and black cables to the power, and ignore the other cables.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this will require soldering, and I'm not 100% sure this will work.*

First, take a lightning cable, and cut roughly 2 inches off of the cable on the usb male end. Strip the main wire down a bit, and you should probably be left with 4 mini wires. Take the red and black wires, and connect them to the I/O of the solar panel, via soldering.

Again, I'm not completely sure how a lightning cable works, but I believe this should work.

Here is an example how to get this done: [How to make a Solar USB charger!](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-Solar-USB-charger-simple/)

Comment: Great guide! what is the use of the diode? at the moment im planning to use a 5v regulator, and i don't really understand the function of a diode. Is it used to prevent flowback?

Comment: @DanielEnzlin I didn't put that link in, someone must have edited my answer. I have no idea what a diode is. Your guess is as good as mine. I'd suggest googling it.